# Magento 2- Displaying Custom Category Attribute Option Values alphabatically in dropdown

Tags: magento2, attributes, magento-2.1

If suppose, I want to display Options in alphabetically order for select/multiselect drown-down ADD CMS Block attribute in Magento Admin Category page. What is the best way for doing that?

Note: I am using Magento CE 2.1 version.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by doing override getAttributesMeta() method of \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider.php into your custom module:

```
public function getAttributesMeta(Type $entityType)
    {
        $result = parent::getAttributesMeta($entityType);

        //BOF - Code Customization
        if (isset($result['landing_page']) && isset($result['landing_page']['options'])) {
            //sort landing_page attributes alphabatically
            $blocks = $result['landing_page']['options'];
            $labels = [];
            foreach ($blocks as $key => $value) {
                $labels[$key] = $value['label'];
            }
            array_multisort($labels, SORT_STRING, $blocks);
            $result['landing_page']['options'] = $blocks;
        }
        //EOF - Code Customization

        return $result;
    }
```

This might help to others for similar type issue.

Thank you,